# What is the max altitude of generated terrain?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am looking to find out the maximum height that Minecraft 1.8.8 will generate naturally. I have found altitude distribution graphs, but they all focus on ores. To clarify, I am *not* looking for the maximum build height, but the altitude of the summit of the highest mountain the game will naturally generate.

Comment: Don't the 1.8 patches only go up to 1.8.8?

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I had been working in 1.7.10 all day and I got a little mixed up. I corrected my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any hard limit to how high terrain will generate other than the maximum build height. Here's a mountain generating pretty much right up to the build limit:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Just to double check, that's not with the amplified terrain generation? If not, then this was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Atlantic Yep, normal terrain; seed and coords included in image.